Word for dramatically believing or espousing a theory based on some evidence while dismissing much stronger theories by the same standard
I'm wondering if there's a word for the situation where someone who disbelieves or dismisses ideas with lots of strong evidence (apparently due to failing to meet their standard), is dramatically espousing a new belief based on evidence that doesn't even meet the aforementioned, apparently insufficient standard of evidence.
Similar:

"FUD" and FUD-mongering may apply, but only to the new belief with weak evidence, these terms alone don't capture the hypocrisy aspect.
"Hypocrisy" may apply, but is too general and somewhat requires the person to have made their standard of evidence explicit already
"Irrational" certainly applies, but is too general and may imply that the new belief isn't true (which it may be!) or that the standard-of-evidence which the new belief passes is irrational (which it may not be - it's simply weaker than the standard which is apparently not enough for them to believe stronger theories)

Non-goals:

Some people explicitly disclaim having a consistent standard of evidence for forming new beliefs - this word would not apply to them. It's for people who imply or genuinely think they're being consistent.
Some beliefs are formed and/or conveyed based on more heuristics than just evidence, or with no evidence at all -- this word would not apply to that situation. Here, it's implied or explicit that the new evidence is the reason they believe it (and/or think you should too).

I've seen this play out in several areas, such as the science of nutrition, drugs, evolution, extraterrestrial life, and history. However I'll refrain from giving examples so it doesn't go off topic, and because standards of evidence are obviously subjective.
Goals:

Conveys that the new apparent standard of evidence, however subjective, is objectively weaker relative to the old one.
Conveys that the belief-affirming behavior on display betrays this unacknowledged (or denied) inconsistency.

A compound word or phrase is fine too!
Ideally, the word is in a form that could be used in the same way as e.g. "equivocating".

The basic motivation is always essentially confirmation bias, manifest in various ways, labeled with a wide range of formal and informal terms.

This tactic is usually known as cherry picking. It is somewhat informal.
OED

cherry-pick
transitive. To choose selectively (the most beneficial or profitable
items, opportunities, etc.) from what is available. Also
intransitive.
1966 The agreement is now in force. We cannot cherry-pick any part of
it.
Times 23 July 1/2
1975 - Many customers are trading down to cheaper brands. Others are
doing more ‘cross-shopping’ from store to store, cherry-picking the
specials.  Business Week (Nexis) 19 May 128

A more formal alternative is "being selective"
